# Nested queries in Python SQL results in empty dataframe

Tags: sql

I am trying to do one assignment question on SQL. My question is :

List all the actors who acted in a film before 1970 and in a film after 1990.

This is the DB schema.

[image]

My query states like this:

```
df1= pd.read_sql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(NAME) FROM PERSON WHERE PID IN(SELECT PID FROM M_CAST WHERE MID IN (SELECT MID FROM MOVIE WHERE YEAR>1970 OR YEAR<1990));",conn)
```

The result is an empty dataset.

I even tried with Joins but no luck. My query using join looks like this.

```
Select p.name from Person P join M_Cast MC on MC.PID=P.PID where MC.MID IN(Select MID from movie where year<1970 or year>1990)
```

Both the queries are running without any error but not giving results. I thought I was clear with SQL But not sure where I am wrong here. Could someone please help? I want to know what exactly I am doing wrong

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it the case that you want actors who acted in a movie before 1970 AND ALSO acted in a movie after 1990? Your code doesn't seem to reflect that, but the problem description does.

Comment: Good point, I was in a rush and didn't double check before posting.  I have deleted the answer.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson Yes. Thats exactly I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
Name 
from
Person
where PID in (
--this select finds persons fitting the criteria
select 
MC.PID 
from 
Movie M   join 
M_Cast MC on M.MID = MC.MID
where 
[year] > 1990  --year is a reserved word in most SQL languages and must be in []
intersect --intersect finds all that match both criteria
select 
pid 
from 
Movie M   join 
M_Cast MC on M.MID = MC.MID
where 
[year] < 1970) --year is a reserved word in most SQL languages and must be in []
```